# "Fixing" a sub-view within a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, subview

I have a UIScrollView which contains a view (lets call this "main view") which scrolls along the X and Y axis.

I am trying to transparently overlay a heading over this view which is fixed at the top of the screen (not view) but scrolls along the X axis as the main view does. When the main view scrolls along the Y axis the heading remains at the top of the screen.

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a container view for both your indicator view and the scrollview. Make it the size of the screen.

Add both the `UIScrollView` and your `HeadingView` to this as Subviews. The Heading will then stay still as the scrollview pans. You can update the heading based on messages to a UIScrollViewDelegate you add to the Scrollview. `scrollViewDidScroll:` is the most obvious but you can get other notifications.

Answer (score 1):

I would not put the view in the scrollview at all.  Use the scroll view delegate to catch when the scroll view is panning and move your subview horizontal manually.